# How to configure nginx to serve versioned css and javascript files

Tags: nginx

My css files named main.css?v=1.0.0 , site.css?=v.1.0 .

how to configure nginx to serve this kind of files(not extension with .css or .js but with a version number)

FYI:

all the files are in the right path and erro message in chrome dev tool console is file not found(404)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to access **main.css?v=1.0.0** or **main.css?v=2.0.0** any webserver will point it to the same file, **main.css**
.
Well in your situation coud create a separate location for your versioned file, and then use the next code in the nginx config:

```
location = /main.css {
    if ($arg_v) {
        rewrite ([0-9]+) /where/maincss/versions/stored/main-$avg_v.css last;
    }
    // otherwise default main.css
}
```

The same thing'll be for the any other file